# jquery.post() overrides existing $_POST elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I'm having some problems '`merging`' some elements into a `$_POST` array.
I'm currently using AJAX in order to swap a div's element when a button is clicked, but I also have a form inside this whose values are overridden by the ajax thing. (sorry for the poor explanation; I'm a beginner!)

So I have this jquery code:

```
$.post(url.concat("/profileajax.php"), {
    contentVar: cv
}, function(data) {
    $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
})
```

However because of this code my `$_POST` array contains only the `contentVar` element. What I want to do is to make the function keep the current `$_POST` elements AND add the `contentVar` element after them.

Like

```
$.post(url.concat("/profileajax.php"), { /*Insert values gotten from the form here */ , contentVar: cv
}, function(data) {
    $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
})
```

Comment: Probably easiest if you simply add your `contentVar` as a hidden field to the form, and then serialize the whole form to use as the data object in your AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$.serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();

    var cv = "cvdata";

    data.push({name: 'contentVar', value: cv});

    var url = "http://example.com";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url.concat("/profileajax.php"),
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
        }
    });
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/p86qzup3/3/**